# Polymorphic singleton in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, singleton, activeadmin, polymorphic-associations

I have the following data structure:

```
class BankAccount < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bankable, polymorphic: true
end

class Buyer < ApplicationRecord
  has_one  :bank_account, as: :bankable
end

class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
  has_one  :bank_account, as: :bankable
end
```

I defined additional routing in my `routes.rb`:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :buyers do
    resource :bank_account
  end
  resources :vendors do
    resource :bank_account
  end
end
```

And my ActiveAdmin is:

```
ActiveAdmin.register BankAccount do
  actions :all, except: [:index, :destroy]

  controller do
    defaults singleton: true
    belongs_to :buyer, :vendor, polymorphic: true
  end
end
```

But when trying to create a new `bank_account`, via `admin/buyers/1/bank_account/new`,

I got the following error:

`No route matches {:action=>"index", :buyer_id=>"1", :controller=>"admin/bank_accounts"}`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: i think it should be `resources :bank_account` not `resource :bank_account
`

Comment: @Vishal if `resources :bank_account`, it won't be a singleton. Buyer and vendor `has_one :bank_account`. So this solution won't work

Comment: its not about singleton, you must write plural form with resource in routes file, it won't affect your association. its related to your controller name

Comment: @Vishal I am very confident about `resource`. See a reference here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#configuring-the-rails-router

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment change `resource :bank_account` to `resources :bank_account`. After modifying can you run command `rails routes/rake routes` in console and check if the desired route comes up.

Comment: See my comment above